# Stopping redirect cart page from onepage checkout when product is out of stock

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, onepage-checkout, redirect, out-of-stock

When I stay on onepage checkout page and product is out of stock and when I click on next step it is redirecting cart page due to produc is out of stock So I want to stop to redirect cart page.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to understand what you need. If you need to let him proceed to checkout anyway you can enable `backorders`.

System > Configuration > Inventory > Product Stock Options > Backorders.

Set to `Allow Qty Below 0 and Notify Customer`

If it is not what you are lookig for please add further explaination to your question.

Comment: Hello RiccardoT,when I on checkout page and product is out of stock and then when I click continue button for next step I automatically redirect cart page and throw product is out of stock error message.But I want to stop redirecting cart page from checkout page when product is out of stock. please help me.please